# TypeError: bookFilter.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a bookstore with React-Redux. The code compiles sucessfully but i have the following displayed in the browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIYAw.png)

```js
BookList
src/containers/BookList.js:42
  39 |       <th>Category</th>
  40 |     </tr>
  41 |   </thead>
> 42 |   <tbody>
     | ^  43 |     {bookFilter.map((book) => <Book key={book.id} book={book} remove={removeHandler} />)}
  44 |   </tbody>
  45 | </table>
```

My components:
CategoryFilter component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const CategoryFilter = ({ handleFilterChange, categories }) => (
  <select onChange={handleFilterChange}>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    {categories.map((category) => {
      <option key={category}>{category}</option>;
    })}
  </select>
);

CategoryFilter.propTypes = {
  handleFilterChange: PropTypes.func,
  categories: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
};

CategoryFilter.defaultProps = {
  handleFilterChange: null,
  categories: [],
};

export default CategoryFilter;
```

BookList Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Book from '../components/Book';
import { removeBook, changeFilter } from '../actions/index';
import CategoryFilter from '../components/CategoryFilter';

const BookList = ({ categories }) => {
  const books = useSelector((state) => state.books);
  const filter = useSelector((state) => state.filter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const removeHandler = (e) => {
    const id = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    dispatch(removeBook(id));
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
    dispatch(changeFilter(e.target.value));
  };

  const bookFilter = () => {
    if (filter !== 'all') {
      return books.filter((book) => book.category === filter);
    }
    return books;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CategoryFilter categories={categories} handleFilterChange={handleFilterChange} />
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {bookFilter.map((book) => <Book key={book.id} book={book} remove={removeHandler} />)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

BookList.propTypes = {
  categories: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
};

BookList.defaultProps = {
  categories: [],
};

export default BookList;
```

I cannot figure out why a browser error is thrown saying `TypeError: bookFilter.map is not a function`
I am building a bookstore with React-Redux. The code compiles sucessfully but i have the following displayed in the browser.

Comment: bookFilter is a function so you need to do `bookFilter().map` .

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm so dumb. Have been on this for hours and could not figure that. Haha